# Where is Prince Charming?

Tags: plot-explanation, shrek-2, shrek-forever-after

Plot of fourth *Shrek Forever After* deals with idea that Shrek was never born and therefore Princess Fiona had to save herself.

But, plot of *Shrek 2* shows us that Prince Charming was [charging to the rescue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjLhSlLWMXE&feature=youtu.be&t=28s), missing his opportunity just by a little (to me it sounded like he missed by just few days).

**So, what happened to Prince Charming in the fourth Shrek movie?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Echoing my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72636/20774) on another stack;

At the start of *Shrek : Forever After* we see that Fiona's parents are about to sign their kingdom over to Rumpelstiltskin in return for him using his magic to release Princess Fiona from her curse. The news that Shrek has rescued the Princess literally interrupts the signing ceremony and they tear up the agreement.

Since Prince Charming is attempting to rescue Fiona for the sole purpose of becoming heir to the throne of Far Far Away, if Shrek hadn't rescued Fiona then her parents would have signed the deed, Rumpelstiltskin would become King and there would have been **no need for Charming to rescue Fiona** which explains his total absence from the film:

> **King :** *Nothing is worth more to us than our daughter.*
>
> **Stiltskin:** *Just sign it and all your problems will disappear.*
>
> **Page** : *Your Highness! The Princess! She's been saved! [by Shrek]*
>
> **They tear the agreement in half.**

Presumably he's still living in Far, Far Away, doing whatever it is that princes do when they're not busy.

Comment: For the record, he does appear very briefly in the [credit sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxGtC_a2f7M&feature=youtu.be&t=2m31s)